# How do we evaluate the postfix string with the unary operator?

Tags: java

How can I evaluate a postfix string with the unary operator inside it? For example: 
input="-3.4+4.2*5"
input="3.4+-4.2*5"

I have tried the following code but it gives me error message like:
java.lang.Number Format Exception: empty String

Java Result: 1

Here is the code:

```
public class PostfixEvaluation {

private Stack<Double> st = new Stack<Double>();
private String[] input;

//Constructor
public PostfixEvaluation(String[] postfixExpression) {
    input = postfixExpression;
}

public Double Evaluation(){

    for (int i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
        String symbol=input[i];
        if (isOperator(symbol)) {
            // Operator, simply pop out two numbers from stack and perfom operation
            // Notice the order of operands
            switch (symbol) {
                case "+": st.push(st.pop() + st.pop());     break;
                case "*": st.push(st.pop() * st.pop());     break;
                case "-": 
                    st.push(-st.pop()+st.pop());

                    break;
                case "/": st.push(1 / st.pop() * st.pop()); break;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            // Number, push to the stack
                 st.push(Double.parseDouble(symbol));

        }
    }

    // The final result should be located in the bottom of stack
    // Otherwise return 0.0
    if (!st.isEmpty()) 
        return st.pop();
    else
        return 0.0;
}


/**
 * Check if the character is an operator
 */
public boolean isOperator(String element) {
    if (element.equals( "*" )  || element.equals( "-" )|| element.equals( "/" )||element.equals( "+" )) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

}

//for the input string, I transform it like this

```
        StringBuilder sb2 = new StringBuilder();
        for (char c : postfixString.toCharArray()) {
        if (!Character.isDigit(c) && c != '.') {
            sb2.append(" ").append(c).append(" ");
        } else {
            sb2.append(c);
        }
    }
    String[] arr2 = sb2.toString().split("\\s+");

    PostfixEvaluation answer= new PostfixEvaluation(arr2);
```

Comment: The code defines the input as an array of strings but your example input is a single string. How is the example input being split into an array? Most likely one of the strings in the input array is an empty string and should be discarded.

Comment: I did transformation like this:

Comment: StringBuilder sb2 = new StringBuilder();
        for (char c : postfixString.toCharArray()) {
            if (!Character.isDigit(c) && c != '.') {
                sb2.append(" ").append(c).append(" ");
            } else {
                sb2.append(c);
            }
        }
        String[] arr2 = sb2.toString().split("\\s+");
        
        PostfixEvaluation answer= new PostfixEvaluation(arr2);

Comment: @Sophie Please don't post code in comments. You can see for yourself that it's totally illegible.

Comment: Sorry about that, but I also post it after the original post

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your algorithm for splitting the input into an array produces arrays with empty strings.

Given input = "-3.4+4.2*5" you will end up passing the following array to PostfixEvaluation's constructor:

[, -, 3.4, +, 4.2, *, 5]

The first element of this array is an empty string, which is not accounted for in your Evaluation for loop.

Either revise your algorithm to avoid passing empty strings to your evaluator or check for empty strings in your for loop and ignore them.

P.S. Pro tip for next time: add additional code to your original question rather than posting it into the comments, much easier to read.

**EDIT**

With regards to your question about building up signed operands, you need to keep track of whether or not you should be creating an operand or operator.

```
private static boolean isOperandChar(final char c) {
    return Character.isDigit(c) || c == '.';
}

private static String[] splitPostfixExpression(final String input) {
    final List<String> postfixExpression = new ArrayList<>();
    boolean encounteredOperandStart = false;
    String currentOperand = "";
    for(final char c : input.toCharArray()) {
        if(encounteredOperandStart) {
            if(isOperandChar(c)) {
                currentOperand += c;
            } else {
                // we've encountered an operator char after reading one or more operand characters, 
                // thus we know this character is an operator and not an operand sign
                postfixExpression.add(currentOperand);
                postfixExpression.add(String.valueOf(c));
                currentOperand = "";
                encounteredOperandStart = false;
            }
        } else {
            if(isOperandChar(c)) {
                encounteredOperandStart = true;
            }
            currentOperand += c;
        }
    }
    if(!currentOperand.isEmpty()) {
        postfixExpression.add(currentOperand);
    }
    return postfixExpression.toArray(new String[postfixExpression.size()]);
}
```

Comment: no problem, feel free to upvote or accept the answer if it winds up solving your problem. Best of luck.

Comment: How can evaluate "3+-5" or "3-+5"?

Comment: Can you change the argument to the constructor from a String[] to a different data structure(s)?

Comment: if I change to character, I don't how to manage the decimal point.

Comment: Thank you Matthew, you help me a lot. Have a great day! It is almost Friday morning now.